# Filter View on [Today] and also include blanks

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, filter

I'm trying to set up a way of filtering one of my list views and struggling a bit.

[image]

The first 3 filters are working fine to show the entries with only a date of today or later but when I use the final 'Or' filter to include blanks, it removes the other required criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set view filter as following picture shows.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Emily, unfortunately as I have other filters too, the 'Or' option will remove those required ones.

Is there another way around it to keep all the other filtered criteria?

Comment: Please provide other filters to further troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks Emily, I've just updated my initial comment.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: Thank you so much Emily, that works perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome. If you find any answer helpful to you, please remember to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Add list view filter on view settings page like this:

[image]

For 2nd **Or** filter, keep the value as blank (do not enter anything in the textbox).

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, as I have a couple of other filters, when I add the one you've suggested, it's using the 'Or' to remove the other filters if that makes sense?

Comment: Can you show us what are other filters you have in list view? Try adding other filters first & then date filters at last....Like `<filter 1 > AND  <filter 2>  AND  <Date filter 1> OR <Date filter 2>`.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I've updated the screenshot to show all of the required filters. The 'Or' option for blanks is then removing those required ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Date column filter like below in view:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, as I have a couple of other filters, when I add the one you've suggested, it's using the 'Or' to remove the other filters if that makes sense?

Comment: First you add all your required queries and then add these date filters at the end.